# How to get the error messages wrote into the logs using the NIFI processors

Tags: apache-nifi

is here a way to get the messages from the log using the processors? 
When the *HiveQL processors get an error I like to send the message which is shown into the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [TailFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TailFile/index.html) processor which you could use to tail logs/nifi-app.log (which will contain processor error messages, etc.). This could be in a separate flow that parses the log looking for the desired messages, which can be routed or otherwise handled appropriately (send an email with the error message, e.g.).